# Find needed tags and generating files via template

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I have many files in PHP. I need to create an script to find some **tags**(strings) and generate with them another files.

For example I have this file:

```
file1.php
<html lang="ru">
<html>
     <head>
          <title>**TAG nr 1**</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <p class="description>**Tag nr 2**</p>
     </body>
</html>
```

Script need to get strings from title, and p with `class="description"`.

After this I will generate another file with this **tags**, i have a script for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `DOMDocument` functions from php to get your results. but verify that the html input is valid and catch errors with `try catch`.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

```
$html = '<html lang="ru">
            <head>
                <title>**TAG nr 1**</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p class="description">**Tag nr 2**</p>
            </body>
        </html>';

// prevent XXE injections 
libxml_disable_entity_loader(true);

// create new DOMDocument + load html
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// create xpath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//p[contains(@class, 'description')]");

// list results
foreach ($elements as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeName . "\n";
    echo $node->textContent;
}
```

for the title just create another xpath `$xpath->query("//title");`

Comment: Thanks! It work good. But i can get text from p in this case:
<div class="top-teen">
  
 <!--{img_new}-->
 <p style="font-size:18px">
    Steel Sky HD is an arcade simulator, in which you are given a choice to participate in three different era battles (WWII, modern warfare and future warfare). Game differs from prior versions with its modern graphics and great music!

   </p>
 </div> ??????

Comment: Very huge, I did it just using: 
$element = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@id, 'description')]");